# what should i include in cds.lib file and hdl.var file. where do i include these files while doing simulation using Xcelium tool

Tags: compiler-errors, simulation

I am new in performing simulations. I was trying to explore the Xcelium tool and written a simple adder program. while trying to simulate this file using Xcelium tool it was giving errors like

xmvlog adder.v tb_adder.v
xmvlog: 21.03-s009: (c) Copyright 1995-2021 Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
DEFINE work ./work
|
xmvlog: *W,DLCPTH (./cds.lib,14): cds.lib Invalid path '/home/padl/simulations/adder/work' (cds.lib command ignored).
module adder(input [1:0]a,b,output [1:0]sum);
|
xmvlog: *F,NOWORK (adder.v,1|5): no working library defined.

please help me regarding the issue.

please mention what do we need to include in cds.lib and hdl.var files

please help me regarding the issue.

please mention what do we need to include in cds.lib and hdl.var files

Comment: did you figure out the answer?